# Uno Platform App text rendering problem on Skia.Gtk

Tags: uno-platform

I followed the [Bugtracker tutorial on the Uno Platform page](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/getting-started-tutorial-2.html)

For some reason even simple text boxes don't seem to get rendered correctly on the Skia.Gtk backend. This is what the final example is supposed to look like:

[image]

Here's what I see with Skia.Gtk:

[image]

The description box is supposed to contain some text and label on the slider isn't showing either.

I get no pertinent warnings or errors, which makes it difficult to pin down the source of the problem. I've run the sample on WSL (running Ubuntu 18.04) as well as a real Debian buster machine. Reassuring is that the GUI renders the same on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got in touch with the maintainer and it turns out that TextBox isn't implemented yet. His reponse https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/4578#issuecomment-731268315

That feature is on the roadmap for the upcoming release 3.4 scheduled to be released on December 4th... But it was previously planned for 3.2, so who knows